# Is it possible to use AI to find music that have a distinct tune?

Tags: machine-learning

Without considering lyrics, there are two type of songs: songs that have a distinct tune which you can easily remember, and songs that are the opposite. Can we design a network to identify the songs that have a distinct tune? It's very hard to find good music, I can't get a song that has a distinct tune for even 100+ songs which consumes a lot of time.

Comment: How do you define "distinct"? Unless you know what you're looking for, AI will not help you.

Comment: @Oliver Mason Yes, part of the question is about is there a model to describe distinctness/creativeness/boringness of a music. I'm not even sure if these are subjective things that varies a lot between people.